# Unexplainable "can't modify frozen object" exception

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, exception, object

I have encountered a weird problem twice in the past 2 weeks and it's starting to piss me off.

I have this very simple code :

```
  Rails.logger.debug "Is current_step frozen  ? => #{@current_step.frozen?.inspect}"
  @current_step += 1
```

Has you can (or not) imagine, this is what is displayed on my console :

```
Is current_step frozen  ? => false
Completed   in 264ms

TypeError (can't modify frozen object):
  lib/chuguf/core.rb:44:in `upgrade'
  app/controllers/xml/cheat_controller.rb:6:in `index'
```

Can some one tells me what's happen here ?

I can give more details if required but i don't see how other lines could be relevant. All the code is executed in the current thread.

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not trying to mutate `@current_step` (which isn't possible with integers anyway), you're trying to reassign it. Since reassigning an instance variable means mutating the object the instance variable belongs to (i.e. `self`), you can only do so if `self` is not frozen.

In other words: if you change your debug message to tell your whether `self` is frozen instead of `@current_step`, you'll find out that it is and that's why you get the error.

Comment: Ok you are right :D Now the question is, how to store an object into the cache without freezing it ? :p thanks !